# Why a simple Plot on Raspberry Pi 3 with Mathematica takes 20 seconds?

Tags: wolfram-mathematica

I use a very simple script file `script.m` with

```
Plot[{x}, {x, 0, 1}, PlotLabels -> "Expressions"]
```

I run this like `time wolfram -script script.m`, which gives me

```
real    0m21.314s
user    0m4.100s
sys     0m1.090s
```

If I run `Plot[{x}, {x, 0, 1}]`, it gives me:

```
real    0m2.930s
user    0m2.320s
sys     0m0.230s
```

, so almost 20 seconds faster than the plot with the option. I see a process `WolframFrontEnd` popping up in `top`, when i set the option `PlotLabels`.

So why Plot here talks to the X-Server, what is exactly what i don't want?
Is there an alternative for getting the smooth points Plot[] produces?

Comment: All graphics functionality uses the x server.

Comment: You should take this to mathematica.stackexchange.com